# Optionally running tests in SBT with a custom configuration

Tags: scala, tags, sbt, scalatest

I'm trying to configure my tests such that a subset of them are not run by default but can be run selectively. The solutions that I've found to this problem online suggest tagging the subset of tests and creating a custom configuration in my project definition in `build.sbt`.

This is what I have:

```
  val node = project
    .in(file("node/instance"))
    .dependsOn(...)
    .settings(commonSettings("node"): _*)
    .settings(
      (soliditySources in Compile) ++= Seq(
        baseDirectory.value / "src" / "evmTest" / "resources" / "solidity",
        baseDirectory.value / "src" / "test" / "resources" / "solidity",
        baseDirectory.value / "src" / "precompiledContracts" / "resources" / "solidity"
      )
    )

  val Integration = config("it") extend Test
  scalastyleSources in Test ++= { (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Integration).value }
  val Benchmarks = config("benchmarks") extend Test

  Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument("-l", "iele")
  val Iele = config("iele") extend Test
  Iele / testOptions -= Tests.Argument("-l", "iele")
  Iele / testOptions += Tests.Argument("-n", "iele")

  node
    .configs(Integration, Benchmarks, EvmTest, PrecompiledContracts, Iele)
    .settings(
      inConfig(Integration)(
        Defaults.testSettings ++ BloopDefaults.configSettings ++ Seq(parallelExecution in Test := false)
      ): _*
    )
    .settings(inConfig(Benchmarks)(Defaults.testSettings ++ BloopDefaults.configSettings): _*)
    .settings(inConfig(Iele)(Defaults.testSettings ++ BloopDefaults.configSettings): _*)
```

My tag is:

```
object Iele extends Tag("iele")
```

The problem is that when I run `iele:test` in the sbt shell, the command returns immediately as successful and no tests are run. I suspect it's because the test source files aren't placed in a dedicated `iele` folder, but I'd prefer not to do this. I'm running sbt version `1.4.9`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate sbt Configuration to run the tagged tests.

https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt

You probably want to do something like `testOnly -- -n iele`

Comment: I want `test` or `testOnly` to exclude the tests by default, and I want to add a command that only executes the tests. `testOnly -- -n iele` works but it doesn't help me exclude the tests by default.